# Django - Reverse for 'contextual' with keyword arguments '{'api': ''}' not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class WellInfo(models.Model):
    api = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    well_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_updates = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.well_name
```

**views.py**

```
class ContextualMainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contextual_main.html'


class WellList_ListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'well_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'well_info'
    model = models.WellInfo

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # get string representation of field names in list
        context['fields'] = [field.name for field in models.WellInfo._meta.get_fields()]

        # nested list that has all objects' all attribute values
        context['well_info'] = [[getattr(instance, field) for field in context['fields']] for instance in context['well_info']]

        return context
```

**html**

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    {% for field in fields %}
    <th>{{ field }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for well in well_info %}
  <tr>
    {% for value in well %}
    <td><a href="{% url 'eric_base:contextual' api=well.api %}">{{ value }}</a></td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from eric_base import views as base_views

app_name = 'eric_base'

urlpatterns = [

        re_path(r'^(?P<api>\d+)/$', base_views.ContextualMainView.as_view(), name='contextual'),

]
```

In my `models.py`, I set `api` as my primary key, and want to use `api` as a unique url identifier, and append it at the end of url, like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/well_list/contextual/api_number_1
http://127.0.0.1:8000/well_list/contextual/api_number_2
http://127.0.0.1:8000/well_list/contextual/api_number_3
```

I think I'm missing something in my `views.py` or `models.py`, but I don't know what it is. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp `(?P<api>\d+)` is for a number, but the `api` field is a `CharField`.

Try `(?P<api>.+)`, it'll match everything, not just digits.

Comment: that didn't solve my problem. I get this error then: 
Reverse for 'contextual' with keyword arguments '{'api': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['well_list\\/contextual/$(?P<api>.+)/$']

Comment: Ah, if you look at the keyword argument, it means you're calling `{% url %}` with an empty string. Are you sure `well.api` is a thing?